# With CSS, can I change the background to multiple div tags when I hover over one?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to use javascript as little as possible on this project.  I would like to create a a voting thing on my site, with stars.

I will have 5 stars, sort of faded out, and when the user rolls over the first, the first will light up, and then they roll over the second, both the second and first light up, until they reach the fifth star, when all stars will be lit.

I tried surrounding them with div tags, so that they would be grouped, but it made all five stars light up every time.

I tried adjusting the z-index of the groups, so that I could hover over the first stars first, but that didn't work either.

Perhaps this can't be done in CSS, but I feel like there should be some shortcut to it.  Let me know if you can think of anything.

Here's the JSFiddle that I'm working off of: [Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/LL9pH/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix" id="stars">
    <div class="darn">Oh no!</div>
    <div class="star off"></div>
    <div class="star off"></div>
    <div class="star off"></div>
    <div class="star off"></div>
    <div class="star off"></div>
    <div class="brilliant">Thanks!</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clearfix div {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

#stars {
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.star {
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/Full_Star_Blue.svg/64px-Full_Star_Blue.svg.png) no-repeat;
 }

.star:hover {
    background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Full_Star_Yellow.svg/64px-Full_Star_Yellow.svg.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.group {
    position:absolute
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, this grouping of divs inside div might work (only FF tested, though, but you get the picture)
http://jsfiddle.net/LL9pH/1/

[edit] fixed the text positioning still, http://jsfiddle.net/LL9pH/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix" id="stars">
    <div class="darn">Oh no!</div>
    <div class="star off">
        <div class="star off">
            <div class="star off">
                <div class="star off">
                    <div class="star off"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brilliant">Thanks!</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.star .star { 
    margin-left: 70px;
}

.brilliant {
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: -64px;
}
```

Comment: So good. Thank you. I tried this, but it didn't work without the margin-left, and I may not have thought to put a .star .star declaration! Thanks! I'm going to change the margin to 64px, so there are no gaps.  Works great.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery prevAll() function.

```
<div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
</div>
```

put for the class star your normal bg image

```
<script>
  $("document").ready(function(){
    $(".star").hover(function(){
      $(this).css("background-image", "imageurl");
      $(this).prevAll().css("background-image", "imageurl");
    });
  });
</script>
```

That should solve your problem

Comment: I think you could include '.star' in .prevAll() and this should work fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you were going in the right direction.
html

```
<div id="stars">
    <div class="star">
      <div class="star">
        <div class="star">
            <div class="star">
                <div id="innermost" class="star">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.star {
display:block;
width:20px;
height:20px;
margin:0px;
padding-left:20px;
background:#00f;
border-left:1px solid #f00;
}
#innermost {padding-left:0px;}
#stars .star:hover{background:#ff0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MpmMa/

Comment: Really nicely done.  I'll have to try this out if the accepted answer fails on a browser.  Thanks!

Comment: The accepted answer and mine are the same technique, just implemented slightly differently. I was a bit slow to post.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have an accepted answer, but you do not need to change your HTML structure, just your CSS very slightly:

```
.clearfix div {
    float:right;        /* changed from left to right */
    position:relative;
}

.star:hover,
.star:hover ~ .star {      /*  add sibling combinator */
    ...
}
```

Of course you will have to switch "oh no" and "thanks" around, but this is a much tidier approach.

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LL9pH/8/**

Comment: Why does the sibling combinator not include the stars after the hovered star?

Comment: @bozdoz It does, but the stars are floating right to left, so the stars "after" the hovered star are actually before the hovered star in HTML. Since CSS cascades, these stars are not styled.

Comment: So sibling combinator only affects the stars after the hovered star?

Comment: @bozdoz The sibling combinator, in respect to this question, will select any `.star` elements that are preceded by the `.star:hover` element. Here is a great link summarising [30 useful CSS selectors](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/). The Sibling Combinator is number 9.