# Display inline DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just created a star rating system that change image on mouse over., but i cant seem to display the stars inline.
they get under each other. 
It dosent work with style sheet so I suppose it should be re written in the javascript. !?

This is my JavaScript function.

html code :

```
<div id="star">
<div id="star_1" onclick="SendRating(1);" onmouseover="rateStar(1)" >
<img src="star2.png" id="rating_1" onclick="SendRating(this.getAttribute('score'));" alt="star_1" /></div>
<div id="star_2" onclick="SendRating(2);" onmouseover="rateStar(2)" >
<img src="star2.png" id="rating_2" onclick="SendRating(this.getAttribute('score'));" alt="star_2" /></div>
<div id="star_3" onclick="SendRating(3);" onmouseover="rateStar(3)" >
<img src="star2.png" id="rating_3" onclick="SendRating(this.getAttribute('score'));" alt="star_3" /></div>
<div id="star_4" onclick="SendRating(4);" onmouseover="rateStar(4)" >
<img src="star2.png"  id="rating_4" onclick="SendRating(this.getAttribute('score'));" alt="star_4" /></div>
<div id="star_5" onclick="SendRating(5);" onmouseover="rateStar(5)" >
<img src="star2.png"  id="rating_5" onclick="SendRating(this.getAttribute('score'));" alt="star_5" /></div>


<p id="ContentHolder">

</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
function rateStar(rating){
        var i = 1;
        var ratings = '';
        for (i==1; i<=5; i++){
            if (i<=rating){
                document.getElementById('rating_'+i).src= 'star1.png';
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('rating_'+i).src= 'star.jpg';
            }
        }
 }
```

and one of my divs

```
<div id="star_1" onclick="SendRating(1);" onmouseover="rateStar(1)" >
<img src="star.jpg" id="rating_1" onclick="SendRating(this.getAttribute('score'));" alt="star_1" /></div>
```

CSS

```
#star{
position:absolute;
color:#fff;
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:1000px;
display:inline block;

}
```

the mouse over function is working great except that it wont display inline  =/
Thanks

Comment: IDs have to be unique. You should create a `<div class="rating_1">`, and add the corresponding CSS style: `.rating_1 {width:50px;height:50px;background:url("star1.png");}`, for example.

Comment: What CSS did you try? The solution is CSS, not JavaScript.

Comment: Did you try: `display: inline;` on the `div` element?

Comment: I did try display:inline on the div element.
I created a new div element, tried different class. etc And the Ids are unique.

Comment: Maybe this question could be of help also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804679/with-css-can-i-change-the-background-to-multiple-div-tags-when-i-hover-over-one/8804749#8804749

Comment: Solved it by using 

#star_1{float:left;}
#star_2{float:left;}
#star_4{float:left;}
#star_5{float:left;}
#star_3{float:left;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `display: inline-block;` on your stars will fix the problem. You can do the whole hover effect using CSS without any Javascript.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/5JPDX/

HTML:

```html
<div id="stars">
    <div id="star-1" class="star"></div>
    <div id="star-2" class="star"></div>
    <div id="star-3" class="star"></div>
    <div id="star-4" class="star"></div>
    <div id="star-5" class="star"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#stars {
    background-image: url( http://thinkingstiff.com/images/star-empty.gif );
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}

.star {
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}

.star:hover {
    background-image: url( http://thinkingstiff.com/images/star-highlight.png );
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}

#star-1 {
    right:  80px;
    z-index: 5;
}

#star-2 {
    right:  60px;    
    z-index: 4;
}

#star-3 {
    right:  40px;    
    z-index: 3;
}

#star-4 {
    right:  20px;    
    z-index: 2;
}

#star-5 {
    right:  0;    
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Script:

```js
document.getElementById( 'stars' ).addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

    //SendRating( event.target.id.substr( -1 ) );
    alert( event.target.id.substr( -1 ) );

}, false );
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`float:left;` `display:inline;` or `display:inline block;` are all your friends when trying to display in a straight horizontal line. I won't suggest using a `<TABLE>` for this but it can be done that way.

Maybe you should post some more of your code or create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your HTML/CSS/Javascript

**Update:**

Created this: http://jsfiddle.net/Uyr4P/

It's just a copy/paste of your HTML with a `display:inline-block` style added for `DIV`s to illustrate how it is all in one line.

You will instead probably want to place a rule on your outermost DIVs and control the display that way - alternatively, use `SPAN`s instead of `DIV`s

DIV solution. Just use this with your current HTML:

```
DIV#star DIV
{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I have tried al that in different ways :) but still hustling with me. going to edit my question and add all my code.

Comment: When you re-write: focus on the HTML/CSS As epascarello mentioned in the comments this is a CSS problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS property "display" not on parent DIV, but on child ones, because it cannot be inherited. So, do something like this in CSS:

```
#star_1{display:inline block;}
#star_2{display:inline block;}
#star_3{display:inline block;}
#star_4{display:inline block;}
#star_5{display:inline block;}
```

or (better) declare CSS class for it

Comment: Why not use CSS on a parent DIV? That's what the "C" in CSS is for - "cascading" the style to the child DIVs.

Comment: Soved it with float:left on every star :)

Thank you !!

Comment: To Matthew. "display" property is not inherited by child tags, see specs. Don't downvote if you don't know about it.
To Felipe. Please accept this answer if that was helpful.

Comment: I misunderstood completely. I thought you were saying `DIV.star DIV {display:inline-block;}` was wrong. I owe you an upvote. BTW, use @Matthew to get a user's attention.